how to use the #Preview macro in Xcode
how to refactor this code to Xcode 15 and make preview works?
struct HistoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var history: History {
        History(attendees: [
            DailyScrum.Attendee(name: "Jon"),
            DailyScrum.Attendee(name: "Darla"),
            DailyScrum.Attendee(name: "Luis")
        ],
                transcript: "Darla, would you like to start today? Sure, yesterday I reviewed Luis' PR and met with the design team to finalize the UI...")
    }
    
    static var previews: some View {
        HistoryView(history: history)
    }
}

I don't know how to use this new #Preview, help!

What errors did you get when you try?

You can convert to #Preview macro style like this:
#Preview {
    var history: History {
        History(attendees: [
            DailyScrum.Attendee(name: "Jon"),
            DailyScrum.Attendee(name: "Darla"),
            DailyScrum.Attendee(name: "Luis")
        ],
                transcript: "Darla, would you like to start today? Sure, yesterday I reviewed Luis' PR and met with the design team to finalize the UI...")
    }

    return HistoryView(history: history)
}

